# add original subject to mailto link

Tags: html, email

Hello I wan't to put a simple Unsubscribe link in all outgoing emails. So far I have this:

`<a href="mailto:yourlist@yourdomain?subject=Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe Me</a>`

The problem is that in the mail I'd also like to have the original e-mail's subject and sender

Is it possible to dynamically build a link that would also include original message's sender and subject?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just add a link with the correct subject in it to the email?

Comment: I need the subject to be copied from the email that contained my Unsubscribe Me link. The sender as well (for example as a string in the body)

Comment: So isn't there a way to do that when generating the email? The problem is that JavaScript functionality of mail clients is highly limited and very different from client to client.

Comment: Depending on your server side language, you could handle the building and processing of an email and have full control of the subject line, content, recipients, etc.  However if you need to be dependant on a 3rd party email client like gmail or something, this might not be possible.  Maybe look to see if Gmail has an API to accept these kinds of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do it all pre-send. You could add dynamic parts/variables that would be set based on who you sent it to.

Most email service providers offer this service under the terms "[merge tags](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/personalization/)", or "[dynamic content](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/dynamic-content/)". You could mimic this yourself if you have the serverside know how. Otherwise check out Mailchimp or Campaign Monitor (linked).

Comment: I guess I should have mention at the beginning that the mail with the link would be outgoing from Exchange 2007. It would appear that I'd have to do some server side programming. Can anyone share some pointers or examples to start me in the right direction?